# Use a regular expression in Sublime Text2

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm trying to use regular expression to make some search and replace in `Sublime Text2`.

Actually, I want to search :
`lang___settings_datetime_infos___xxx` or 
`lang___settings_user___xxx` or 
`lang___kardex_edit___xxx`

and replace by:
`lang___xxx`

How I need to use this function ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: is xxx literal or variable?

Comment: It's literal. Thanks.

Comment: Find `lang___.*___xxx` and replace with `lang___xxx`